# Pass data to Tab table view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a 2 Table View Controllers (A and B) inside a Tab Controller. This tab controller is called programmatically.

I have a few problems:
1) How do assign a view controller to the tab controller? (Either via code or in storyboard)
2) How do I populate the table controllers programmatically?

I've created a Tab controller class, but it does not appear as a selectable option in the storyboard. Also the View Did Load methods of either table controller never get called so I can't populate them. What do I do?

Edit:
By assign a view controller I mean say which controller class is attached to that tab controller. So I can use custom methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered why assigning a tab bar controller class file to the controller in storyboard wasn't working: Xcode wasn't updating the list of UITabBarControllers. I solved this via closing Xcode and reopening it. I think that was also why the view did load methods were not being called. They are being called now.

Since I solved those problems I was able to solve my problem of populating the tables by making a database call inside the view did load methods and so got the data I needed. To anyone reading this there are tutorials online for getting data from an array and putting it into a table. I can link to them if asked.

Answer (score 0):

Just CTRL-drag from your tab view controller, and create a relationship segue to the view controllers that you want as tabs. It's that easy. (In storyboard that is)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already linked the table views to my tab view - I can navigate to my tab controller and switch between the table views via tabs. But I can't populate them via code.

Edit: I don't think I wrote my question clearly sorry - I mean assign a view controller code file, so I can make custom methods and call them via the object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use – **tabBar:didSelectItem:** (delegate method of Tab bar) then put a condition to check for which table is to be present and continue with ur logic and reload the particular table.

Comment: Is this delegate method is placed inside the table view controller?

Comment: this is delegate method of tab bar controller. So when u tap on any tabBar item then this method is fired and you could know which table view will come along performing some operation as per u needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about creating a class for the UITableViewController, then press cmd + n and create a new Objective-C class and make it a subclass of UITableViewController. after doing so, go to you Storyboard and select the view controller, on the right menu choose "Identity Inspector" and set the custom class name to the name of the class you just created.

After reading your comments, I hope this answers your question. Although its better if you edit the question to say what you actually mean.

Comment: That's what I'd done but for some reason it wasn't working. It turns out that it DID work with a different controller class I put in there just in case something was wrong with my code. The proper view controller is working now, not sure why as I didn't change any code as far as I know. Either way now I need to access the tab bar from the table view controller to dismiss it, but I'll post a separate question for that.